# Login using additional parameters in LDAP

Tags: ldap, websphere, ldap-query

We have integrated Websphere commerce with LDAP and the proper login flow is working fine.

We have a requirement that user can have an option to login using his phone number and also his membership card.

Currently we are storing the ph.no and membership card in LDAP database also.

We are unable to use these fields for login as well. Can someone give some pointers on the same?

Comment: Which version of WebSphere are you running?

Answer (score 1):

WAS has Standalone and Federated LDAP authentication.

Standalone LDAP configs in WebSphere allow you to construct your own LDAP search that's used to map a web username to a DN. You can list multiple attributes using LDAP filter syntax (|(phone=%v)(membershipcard=%v)...

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_ldapfilter.html

> Modify the user filter, if necessary. The user filter is used for
>   searching the registry for users and is typically used for the
>   security role-to-user assignment. The filter is also used to
>   authenticate a user with the attribute that is specified in the
>   filter. The filter specifies the property that is used to look up
>   users in the directory service. In the following example, the property
>   that is assigned to %v, which is the short name of the user, must be a
>   unique key. Two LDAP entries with the same object class cannot have
>   the same short name. To look up users based on their user IDs (uid)
>   and to use the inetOrgPerson object class, specify the following
>   syntax: (&(uid=%v)(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)

Federated registries take a semi-colon separated list of LDAP attribute names used for the same purpose.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twim_ldap_settings.html :

> All login properties are searched during login. If multiple entries or
>   no entries are found, an exception is thrown. For example, if you
>   specify the login properties as uid;mail and the login ID as Bob, the
>   search filter searches for uid=Bob or mail=Bob. When the search
>   returns a single entry, then authentication can proceed. Otherwise, an
>   exception is thrown.

Both are covered in gory detail in the manual.